# Why is cron mailing me program output even though I've redirected to /dev/null?

Tags: linux, cron

I'm trying to restart a system process through cron and getting emailed the startup output of the process. I thought redirecting STDOUT and SDTERR to /dev/null would "silence" the output but alas, this has not work. How can I get cron to silently restart this service?
crontab entry:

```
0 6 * * * service sympa stop &>/dev/null; service sympa start &> /dev/null
```

sample output from restart email:

```
 Stopping Sympa bounce manager bounced
   ...done.
 * Stopping Sympa task manager task_manager
   ...done.
 * Stopping Sympa mailing list archive manager archived
   ...done.
 * Stopping Sympa mailing list manager sympa
   ...done.
 ... waiting Prototype mismatch: sub Lock::LOCK_SH () vs none at /home/sympa/bin/Lock.pm line 38.
Constant subroutine LOCK_SH redefined at /home/sympa/bin/Lock.pm line 38.
Prototype mismatch: sub Lock::LOCK_EX () vs none at /home/sympa/bin/Lock.pm line 39.
Constant subroutine LOCK_EX redefined at /home/sympa/bin/Lock.pm line 39.
Prototype mismatch: sub Lock::LOCK_NB () vs none at /home/sympa/bin/Lock.pm line 40.
Constant subroutine LOCK_NB redefined at /home/sympa/bin/Lock.pm line 40.
```

Comment: Your redirections are about-face; try `service sympa stop >&/dev/null`, and the other likewise.  At the moment not only are you only redirecting STDOUT (and thus getting STDERR by mail), you're backgrounding the commands as well, which means they will run concurrently not consecutively - not at all what you want, I suspect.

Comment: Actually, &>word is the preferred (according to the bash man page) way to write that redirect. >&word will also work but is not preferred.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.`>&/dev/null` produces `/bin/sh: Syntax error: Bad fd number`

Comment: &> was introduced with version 4 of bash. are you possibly trying this on a server with bash 3? did you remember to put a SHELL=/bin/bash in your cron?

Comment: I think you'd want `service sympa stop >/dev/null 2>&1`. The first command sends stdout to `/dev/null` then `2>&1` causes `stderr` to be sent to where `stdout` is going which is `/dev/null` resulting in supressing output.

Comment: Ahhhh, yeah that was it. Adding `SHELL=/bin/bash` fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: &>word is not a bash 4 addition but it isn't bourne compatible. There's a difference between >&# and >&word. >&# is portable >&word (and &>word) seem not to be.

Comment: val0x00ff - your suggestion works also even without adding the `SHELL` assignment. I've never seen it done like that before but I like that it's not shell dependent.  I think you should make your reply an answer so I can close the question.

Comment: @ServerFault as requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'd want the following line

`service sympa stop >/dev/null 2>&1`.

The first command sends stdout to `/dev/null` then `2>&1` causes `stderr (standard error)` to be sent to where `stdout(standard output)` is going which is `/dev/null` resulting in supressing output.

Comment: Nice work, val0x00ff; serve me right for thinking short cuts!

Comment: @MadHatter it makes it more readable in my opinion and maybe easier to remember when referring to `stderr` or `stdout`